# How to save a data(String or Int) permanently in application until the app uninstall

Tags: android

How to save a data(String or Int) permanently in application until the app uninstall ?
 .. (i.e data need to be exists after clear cache/data option is used).

Comment: If i clear local-cache  data will be deleted right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a coupe options. Internal storage, external storage, shared preferences, and database. Here is a link that describes them all:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html